# Using Regex as conditional in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I am having trouble trying to use Regex to check if each character in string is an alphabet.

First let me introduce the problem itself.
There is a string mixed with special chars and alphabets and suppose to return the number of alphabets only.

My code/pseudo code for problem is :

```
//Create var to hold count;
var count = 0;
//Loop thru str
for(let char of str){
//Check if char is a alphabet 
    ***if(char === /[A-Za-z]/gi){***
    //if so add to count
    count ++;
}
//return count; 
    return count;
}
```

How can I use Regex in a conditional statement to check if each char is an alphabet???? 
Please help!

Comment: maybe regexp [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) ?

Comment: Just use this regex `/^[a-z]+$/i` to validate your input.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const pattern = /[a-z]/i
const result = [...'Abc1'].reduce((count,c) => pattern.test(c) ? count+1 : count, 0)

console.log(result) // 3
```

Comment: What a slow method, creates one regexp per character.

Comment: Good spot. Updated.